# Does the 'last cavalry charge' question belong on the site?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/230/when-was-the-last-cavalry-charge) immediately attracted my attention because I was pretty sure I knew the answer off the cuff. Checking my facts a trivial [Google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=last%20cavalry%20charge%20of%20the%20war) confirmed the answer I was going to post.

Does this sort of stuff belong on the site or am I being obnoxious?

**Update**

So it seems my confidence in the March 1st 1945, 1st Warsaw Cavalry Brigade charge being the accepted "last cavalry charge" may be unfounded. In this case I think it has value, assuming it results in an answer that provides a more recent example.

Comment: The wiki link has several masquerading as the "last".  Maybe the question is not clear (last date, last real charge, ...) but the answer is not clear.  As far as I am aware, Tibetan cavalry forces did charge Chinese units during the last  conquest of Tibet. But I cannot find accurate facts.  The question was meant as a catch all to check if I was accurate in my thinking or wrong since there could have been one later.

Answer (score 4):

It's a perfectly valid historical question in my view. Sure, the answer may be hard to come by and the history in general may be poorly documented, but that shouldn't stop people providing *evidenced* answers.

We just need to encourage people to provide citations where appropriate, as it provides a basis of how trustworthy their answer might be in cases like this. This really needs to be stressed.

Comment: Yep. I think that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question.  It may not have an answer that will always be true.  That is not the fault of the question and can be used as part of the answer.

Comment: Yep. I think I was probably being fickle ;)

Comment: @RedBlueThing: Not at all.  These things should be raised.  Thanks for doing so.

Comment: @Sardathrion Thanks for being so gracious about that :) ... also thanks for all the awesome Japanese history questions. I have been having a great time digging through all my Japanese history books.

Comment: @RedBlueThing: You are most welcome on all counts.  I have many many more questions about the Sengoku-jidai and the Meiji restoration in store.  I am trying not to spam the site with too many of them at once.